# I want to convert my array values from float to double to get smaller values

Tags: c

When I change the type of array from float to double (float array[][] to double array[][]), it doesn't scan the values correctly. All the values become zero. For example, if I enter 5 for input when it's float, it's 5.000000. However, when it's double, every value I enter is scanned as 0.0000000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    int limestone, min=0;
    //for entering height of array (number of limetstone)
    printf("Enter number of limestone: ");
    scanf("%d", &limestone);
    float array[limestone][3];
    //double array[limestone][3]; (the problem)
    //for getting inputs
    for(int i=0;i<limestone;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the %d porosity, hydraulic conductivity (m/s), specific gravity: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f %f %f", &array[i][0], &array[i][1], &array[i][2] );
    }
    //for print array (you can remove it)
    for(int i=0;i<limestone;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            printf("%f ",array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //Comparing 3rd (Last) Column
    for(int i=limestone-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(array[i][2]<array[min][2])
        {
            min=i;
        }
    }
    printf("The limestone with the lowest specific gravity is Limestone %d with a specific gravity of %f",min+1,array[min][2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please show the input you're providing to your program when you run it.

Answer (score 1):

I got your code to work by changing your scanf line to

```
scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &array[i][0], &array[i][1], &array[i][2] );
```

All I did was change the %f's to %lfs.

This works for me at least, I think it's doing what you want

Comment: **Will** do for everyone, as it is the standard, in standard library `stdio.h`.

Comment: I tested it out. when you use %lf, it doesn't work.

=====
Input:
* Limestone: 2
* Array {{1, 2, 0.00002}, {3, 4, 0.000005}}

(Your) Output:
* 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 
* 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 
* The limestone with the lowest specific gravity is Limestone 1 with a specific gravity of -0.000000

(Right) Output:
* 1 2 0.00002
* 3 4 0.000005
* The limestone with the lowest specific gravity is Limestone 1 with a specific gravity of 0.000002

Comment: It should. Did you change your code back to using  doubles? Here's the code I have. Works just fine https://onlinegdb.com/S4nepGxZr